# AccessViolationException when opening Excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openfiledialog, exceldatareader

I'm using .net 4.0. I used an `OpenFileDialog` to read data from an Excel sheet. At the first time the `OpenFileDialog` works great and I get the file but after I close it and reopen it to get another file the ***AccessViolationException*** shows up.

The code:

```
private void excelFileOpenBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
   openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

   if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      String filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

      if (filename == String.Empty)
         return;

      fileNameLb.Text = filename;
      FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

      //Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
      IExcelDataReader excelReader2003 = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

      DataSet result = excelReader2003.AsDataSet();

      String txt = "";
      foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Table");
         for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
               txt += "\"" + table.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] + "\";";
               txt += "----";
         }
      }
      MessageBox.Show(txt);
      excelReader2003.Close();
      stream.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: You are either attempting to read or write to a protected memory block.

Comment: .NET Framework Version 4.0